# Drupal accounts with dead addresses: how to de-activate?

Tags: emails

on my drupal website, there are a lot of users with an invalid email address. I know because, either they have never logged in or their mails bounce. But I have to check manually, which is not good.

When a user signs up with an email address, they receive a confirmation email. Is there a way to automatically disable an account if the user does not log in within the first day after receiving this confirmation mail?

Alternatively, it would be OK to keep the accounts disabled until the user clicks a link on the confirmation mail.

Are there plugins or settings in Drupal to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Drupal's [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module does this. In the settings, there is an option to "Delete unvalidated users after:" and then you select a time period. It runs with cron so you can "set it and forget it."

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [Inactive User](http://drupal.org/project/inactive_user) module.

Comment: Not really. That module tracks users that have not visited the site for a long period. I want to make sure that their email is valid, and remove (or: not create) their account otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about drupal specific plugins, but I think most sites keep users inactive until they click the confirmation link if asked (otherwise why send a confirmation). Alternatively I've seen several sites with an expiration on their confirmation - IE

"you're seeing this because you signed up on example site, please confirm by clicking the link below, if this is a mistake then do nothing and the account will be closed in 24hours"

Comment: That's exactly what I need, but it seems like Drupal does not support that procedure out of the box.